# Using a HDD and an SSD for /home/username folder on CentOS server

Tags: centos, mount

I have a server running CentOS 6.3 installed on a 2TB HDD. I also have a 250GB SSD. My aim for this setup is to have low IO applications run in /home/username folder stored on the HDD but also allow each user to have their own individual folder on the SSD for high IO applications.

I have tried using the mount command which success however when the server restarts these mounts are dropped. I could use the fstab file but I need these mounts to be automated.

The reason I would like these applications to be in the same place is so users can access their files over FTP.

My solution was to mount the SSD in say /ssd and write this into the fstab file and inside /ssd I would have /ssd/username/ and then have the fast IO applications stored there. Then mount that folder inside the users home dir. Which is where I was stuck with the restart problem.

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount the SSD onto /ssd, and create /ssd/username/ directories, as you have done, and then create a symlink from /home/username/ssd into /ssd/username for each user.

The other option is to do a bind mount of /ssd/username into /home/username/ssd, but that doesn't really give you anything more than a symlink does, and it's a more complicated process (you'll need fstab entries for every user, unless you can persuade one of the various automount systems to do it for you).

I'd just use a symlink, myself.

Comment: As far as I know symlink don't work over FTP do they? Which was my main reason for going with the mounting. If it comes down to it I can always write a small script to remount all the drives on a restart. I was just hoping for a more elegant way to do it :)

Comment: @user2126881 There is nothing inherent in an FTP server that would prevent it from using symlinks, but some can be configured to not follow them for security reasons.

Comment: @SvenW If i'm mounting the drive outside of the home folder and not allowing users to venture beyond their home directory wouldn't the symlinks fail to work for FTP?

Comment: @user2126881 that would be one of the security reasons that SvenW alluded to.  If you can't relax that, then I think you'll have to look at bind mounts, either manually or via an automounter.

Comment: Ok great thanks. I think i'll have to go with an automounter then.